# What can I use instead of a CD4007 transistor?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, power-electronics, optoelectronics

What can I use instead of a **CD4007** transistor, or how can I simply design a "**20 watt** or larger" speaker using a "**TBA810**" or any available widely available and used IC?
I found this circuit: [Touch Volume Controlled Amplifier Circuit](http://www.electronicecircuits.com/electronic-circuits/touch-controlled-amplifier), And I can't seem to find that kind of a transistor.

Comment: Depends on the circuit, show a schematic.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [CD4007](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4007ub.pdf). They are widely available. They are not a transistor but a very inexpensive 4000-series chip with a number of interconnected transistors inside.

[image]

There are other parts that could be substituted, but you may as well get the original since it's as (or more) available than anything else.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could never find it down here. but can I just design it?!

Comment: You can try 2N7000 transistors and if you can't find those (both have been jellybean parts for 30 or 40 years) maybe consider moving or taking up another hobby!

Comment: I did find another circuit and I really liked it and all of its components are available... I guess. You can take a look and see if that works xD
http://www.circuitstoday.com/150-watt-amplifier-circuit
thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Forget that circuit. It will not work in the long run. It depends on the voltage across C1 to set the volume, and in any real circuit you make that voltage will not remain constant. Instead, the capacitor voltage will drift, depending on things like your soldering/defluxing technique, the materials you use, the geometry of the component layout, and the humidity of the air.

Second, Google is your friend. However, since the data sheet for a TBA810 says that it is a 7 watt amplifier, why do you think you can find a 20 watt circuit?